# Reading files in PIG where delemeter comes in data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to read a CSV file using PIG what should i Do?. I used load n pigstorage(',') but it fails to read CSV file properly because where it encounters comma (,) in data it splits it.How should i give delimeter now if i have comma in data also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [CSVLoader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html) loader in the [PiggyBank](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html#piggybank) if you want to read a CSV file? (of course the file format needs to be valid)

Comment: what if i want to store file as CSV..i got CSVExcelStorage but its not there in piggybank.jar and  i am not able to build it..any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally impossible to distinguish comma in data from comma as a delimiter.
You will need to escape that comma that is in your 'data' and custom load function (for Pig) that can recognize escaped commas.

Take a look here:
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/load_and_store_funcs.html
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Load%2FStore+Functions

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you have a valid CSV file. In the case you haven't try to change the source file through Excel (if the file is small) or other tool and export a new CSV with a good delimiter for your data (Ex: \t tab, ; , etc). Even better can be do another extract with a "good" delimiter.

Example of your load can be then something like this:

> TABLE = LOAD 'input.csv'  USING PigStorage(';') AS (  site_id: int, 
>   name: chararray, ... );

Example of your DUMP:

> STORE TABLE INTO 'clean.csv' using PigStorage(','); <- delimiter that suits you best